# Pc lpt (parallel) port input pin, how much current does it draw

Tags: current, parallel, pcie, cnc

I need some help to understand what's going on with my project:
I am building an cnc machine and i use the parallel port to communicate with it...
I use the native port to drive the motors and emergency stop. ( i purchased st v2 5 axis board which works fine)
For the limit switches i use a second lpt port provided by a pci express card.
Here i face the problem, with this card...
My limit switches are sn04-p2 (10v to 30v pnp normal closed)
I've built a board using octocouplers (pc123) 
Since i can't feed 10v or 12v or 30v dirrectly to the lpt port.
So what does this board do? Isolates the 12v (currently used by limit switches) from the 5 volts that is feed into the lpt port to keep the pin high...

The optocoupler works, but i can't provide sufficient current on the 5v side to pull up the input pin from the lpt adaptor card...

If i feed 5v directly on the input pin works without problem. (Jumper from usb for example)
So i got my multimeter and measured the current drawn by the input pin ... and is 99-100 mA... which in my opinion is HUGE ...

Anyone know why? Or is this normal?

I feel safe using this "pull up/high" state, because if anything goes wrong with the limit switch, or wires, then no 5v and machine is stopped...

Thanks!

Comment: That would be mA.  If it were mAh, you would have been measuring the capacity of a (small) battery.

Comment: If you really connected 5V directly to the input, you may have damaged it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, mA is correct

Comment: what is the voltage coming out of the lpt card? usually, you would need more volts, not more amps (due to high impedance)

Comment: I didn t measure yet, but i assume is 0.. since the port is configured as input...

Comment: When you set pins 2 to 9 as inputs the voltage is 0.

Answer (score 2):

> The optocoupler works, but i can't provide sufficient current on the 5v side to pull up the input pin from the lpt adaptor card...
>
> If i feed 5v directly on the input pin works without problem. (Jumper from usb for example) So i got my multimeter and measured the current drawn by the input pin ... and is 99-100 mAh... which in my opinion is HUGE ...

From your description, you are trying to drive an output pin as an input, which is a mistake.

Either you are misusing a pin which can only be an output, or else you are using a pin which can be an input in one of the extended modes, but is an output in your present mode.

Especially in the bi-directional case, you should use something like a current limit resist to keep the fault current reasonable in the case where software has not suitably configured the port; preferably you would also have your circuit only try to drive these pins when enabled by software.

Comment: I am using pin 2 to 9 as inputs, also the software have this feature and is's active

Comment: Those pins are normally outputs; rather obviously in your case they still are, and *have not* been configured as inputs.  That could be either a software problem or a hardware one.

Comment: I can assure you they are configured as inputs because if i change them as outputs in software they stop working as inputs...

Comment: You can "assure" all you want, but the simple fact is that if it takes 100 milliamps to pull them up, they are not functioning as proper inputs.  That could be a software problem, a hardware problem with a given port, a design problem with an input clamped to 3v3, or past damage... **but the fact remains that they are not currently functioning as proper inputs**

Comment: Ok, i will buy a new pci express parallel card and see if they work as inputs without drawing 100mAmps...

Comment: It would probably be better to use a more suitable design; most modern CNC controllers are an embedded realtime computer (some as simple as Arduino varients) taking G-code or comparable level commands drip-fed over a serial port or read from a memory card.  Non-localbus ports have often had issues with high step rates anyway.